# Bayesians' positions on inductive skepticism

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, philosophical

Philosopher Marc Lange gives an overview ([pdf](http://stephanhartmann.org/HHL10_Lange.pdf)) of the debate on Hume's Problem of induction. Chapter 9 (starting on p. 80) is called "Bayesian approaches". I understand it as: the justification for induction might be updating believes from a Bayesian point of view. Lange continues with a fictional dialogue between a Bayesian (B) and an inductive skeptic (S). I summarize:

> B: if you admit Bayesian approaches are valid, what kind of prior do
>   you suggest, which fundamentally makes updating believes a
>   non-justification of induction.
>
> S: any distribution with "no degree of confidence to which we are
>   entitled regarding predictions regarding unexamined cases" (Lange),
>   where "no degree of confidence" does not mean the value zero but no
>   value at all [e.g. a NULL in the R language].
>
> B: this prior violates probability axioms - it is not a distribution
>   [and not implementable in R either].

My questions are:

Does B's last claim reflect the working Bayesian's position?

Can the skeptic S consistently defend her skeptical position still including the acceptance of Bayesian techniques by her construction of a prior distribution?

Comment: Your sk vs sc vote is a majority for sk, so I've edited to skeptic and skepticism throughout.

Comment: Generally, questions seeking to "collect opinions" are off topic here (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). Given the large number of upvotes, this may be worthy of an exception. But in that case, it should be made CW. You may also prefer to rework this & post it instead on [philosophy.SE] (note that *primarily opinion-based* is an SE-wide policy so you would have to confront that somehow on either site).

Comment: I took out the opinion-related parts - though I wonder, if the question will be answered without any debate. Moreover, I prefer to keep it on cross-validated and not on Philosophy, as I am really interested (see wording of the first question) in the working Bayesians' point of view.

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, then the statistical part ("Does B's last claim reflect the working Bayesian's position?") is in no doubt - of course one can't set probabilities to NULL (effectively, "undefined") and then update them, since the updating formula refers to these prior probabilities. But the philosophical part ("Can the skeptic S consistently defend her skeptical position") seems better suited to Philosophy SE.

Comment: Replicated this question on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29289/bayesian-statistics-versus-inductive-skepticism/29292#29292

Comment: @Bumble gave an enlightning answer including both statistical and philosophical parts of my questions on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29289/bayesian-statistics-versus-inductive-skepticism/29292#29292